# Material-UI changing the color of inputs floating label

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the color of a floating title for Material-UI's `TextField`.

As stated in documentation, I pass the object color as `floatingLabelStyle`:

```
<TextField floatingLabelStyle={{color: somecolor }} />
```

But this applies to both states of the label - hovering above the input and on the input while out of focus, when it's supposed to be grey.

I guess that I'm overwriting some kind of CSS transition, but have no idea how to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: code or link perhaps?

Comment: <TextField floatingLabelStyle={{color: somecolor }} /> that's the way im trying to do it.

Answer (score 37):

This does the trick

```
  InputLabelProps={{
    style: { color: '#fff' },
  }}
```

Answer (score 10):

You should set style of InputLabel:

```
const styles = {
    floatingLabelFocusStyle: {
        color: "somecolor"
    }
}

<TextField
    label="Test"
    id="test"
    InputLabelProps={{
        className: classes.floatingLabelFocusStyle,
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do that by changing the `InputLabel`'s color inside the `TextField`. `TextField` provides a `InputLabelProps` prop to help you manipulate the label's properties. If you only want to change the color when it is shrinked (floating), you can refer to the `inputLabelClasses.shrink` class name. See the example below:

```
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { inputLabelClasses } from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
```

```
<TextField
  label="Outlined secondary"
  InputLabelProps={{
    sx: {
      // set the color of the label when not shrinked
      color: "red",
      [`&.${inputLabelClasses.shrink}`]: {
        // set the color of the label when shrinked (usually when the TextField is focused)
        color: "orange"
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 35781631/material-ui-changing-the-color-of-inputs-floating-label]

Answer (score 4):

If you're working from a theme, I found that adding this to the overrides section did it

```
overrides: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
      root: {
        color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87)",
      },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use floatingLabelFocusStyle:

```
const styles = {
    floatingLabelFocusStyle: {
        color: "somecolor"
    }
}

<TextField floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.floatingLabelFocusStyle} />
```

Comment: NOTE: **floatingLabelFocusStyle** doesn't work anymore. Instead, use **InputLabelProps**  as suggested in the @Borzh

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
root: {
  '& .MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-disabled': {
    color: 'red',
  },
},
```

```
 <TextField
   label={label}
   disabled={true}
   className={classes.root}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways by which you can change the label color on focus event :

1. Using makeStyle Function :
   Link to the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xnz77
   Explanation: To make things more abstract i have used style.js in which i have used 
   JSS which creates classes using makestyle function. After that i have used Input 
   props:

   `InputLabelProps={{
       classes: {
         root: classes.inputLabel,
         focused: "focused"
       }
     }}`

   and thus creating an textfield which when focussed change the label color.
2. Using withStyles :

   Reference 1: https://codesandbox.io/s/3vzr41zmjm

   Reference 2: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13840

   I havent used the exact code from the references but yes i have modified it a bit to fit my requirements.

   Here is a Link to sandBox https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-s9g4t

Comment: Most detailed answer! Does the same apply to AutoComplete?

Comment: don't exactly know if it works for autocomplete but yes, if perfect classes are used it will definitely work. Please explain it a bit more so i give a full proof answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those using themes with v5 Material UI:

```
MuiInputLabel: {
     styleOverrides: {
          root: {
               color: "white",
          },
          shrink: {
               color: "white",
          }
     }
}
```

This will style both the `InputLabel` inside a TextField and a floating `InputLabel`. If you just want to change the floating then remove the root attributes.

**Note**: You also need the boolean prop for `TextField` shrink to be true

For more CSS rule names check out the [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input-label/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a bug, please raise it with them.**

Explanation

Just went through their source code. Initially the label color is set as `hintColor`.

```
const styles = {
  ...
  floatingLabel: {
    color: hintColor,
    pointerEvents: 'none',
  },
  ...
}
```

On focus, the color of the label is changed to `focusColor` from `muiTheme`

```
if (state.isFocused) {
  styles.floatingLabel.color = focusColor;
}
```

And then overridden if any value is given

```
<TextFieldLabel
  style={Object.assign(styles.floatingLabel, this.props.floatingLabelStyle)}
  ...
>
```

So your property is always overridden and thus you see the same color always.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import {FormControl, Input, InputLabel} from "@material-ui/core";

 <FormControl>
   <InputLabel style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Votre Nom et Prénom</InputLabel>
   <Input value={Nom} onChange={event => setNom(event.target.value)} />
 </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a theme object and pass it to the mui component whose color you want to change

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#f1d045",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#f1d045",
    },
  },
  textField: {
    color: "#f1d045",
  },
});
```

then pass this theme to the component you want to change by the help of `ThemeProvider`

```
<ThemeProvider theme = {theme}>
    <TextField
    id="outlined-search"
    label="Search field"
    type="search"
    />
</ThemeProvider>
```

while doing all this you get an error like `'ThemeProvider' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef`

so to correct this you just have to import this in your jsx file

```
import {ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
```

Answer (score -2):

According v5 Material UI documentation examples https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#customization
TextField colors can be customized with styled() utility

```
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({
  '& label.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'green',
  },
  '& label.Mui-root': {
      color: 'blue',
  },
});

<CssTextField label="Custom CSS"/>
```

Comment: Aleksey, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)